# ActiveRecord throws Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError during simple update after long task

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've a simple script which is responsible for finding a record in the database, doing some long-running calculations and after that, updating the database once again.

Here is the code

```rb
DB_CONFIG = {
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  database: *******,
  username: *******,
  password: *******,
  host: *******,
  reconnect: true,
  read_timeout: 1800,
  write_timeout: 1800,
  connect_timeout: 1800
}.freeze

DBRecord = ActiveRecord::Base
DBRecord.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
DBRecord.establish_connection(DB_CONFIG)

class ReocrJob < DBRecord
  self.table_name = 'reocr_job'
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  begin
    reocr_job = ReocrJob.find(154)
    reocr_job.update(status: ReOCRStatus::PROCESSING)

    @logger.info "Slepping for a while"
    sleep(1000)
    @logger.info "Wake up! We have database to update!"

    reocr_job.update(status: ReOCRStatus::COMPLETED)
  rescue StandardError
    @logger.error "Update Failed"
    @logger.error $ERROR_INFO
    ReocrJob.find(154).update(status: ReOCRStatus::FAILED, comment: $ERROR_INFO.to_s)
  end
  @logger.info 'Done. '
end
```

The second update statement is throwing error (full output with SQL queries logged below).

`Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)`

This error is catched by the rescue block and, surprisingly, the update statement there is working fine! You can see in the SQL debug log that the update statement with error message is working fine.

Here is the full output log:

```
D, [2021-08-31T13:33:45.327712 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   ReocrJob Load (50.5ms)  SELECT `reocr_job`.* FROM `reocr_job` WHERE `reocr_job`.`id` = 154 LIMIT 1
D, [2021-08-31T13:33:45.414542 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (48.9ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-08-31T13:33:45.465169 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   ReocrJob Update (50.3ms)  UPDATE `reocr_job` SET `reocr_job`.`status` = 'processing', `reocr_job`.`updated_at` = '2021-08-31 11:33:45' WHERE `reocr_job`.`id` = 154
D, [2021-08-31T13:33:45.572910 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (106.9ms)  COMMIT
I, [2021-08-31T13:33:45.573033 #1039883]  INFO -- : Slepping for a while
I, [2021-08-31T13:50:25.669822 #1039883]  INFO -- : Wake up! We have database to update!
D, [2021-08-31T13:50:25.723543 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (51.3ms)  BEGIN
E, [2021-08-31T13:50:25.724075 #1039883] ERROR -- : Update Failed
E, [2021-08-31T13:50:25.724176 #1039883] ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `block in query'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `query'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:204:in `execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:50:in `execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:219:in `begin_db_transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `materialize!'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:285:in `block (2 levels) in materialize_transactions'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:285:in `each'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:285:in `block in materialize_transactions'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:282:in `materialize_transactions'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:328:in `materialize_transactions'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:201:in `execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:50:in `execute'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:215:in `execute_and_free'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:76:in `block in exec_delete'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:75:in `exec_delete'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:179:in `update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:22:in `update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:385:in `_update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:891:in `_update_row'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:88:in `_update_row'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:913:in `_update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:195:in `_update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:465:in `block in _update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:824:in `_run_update_callbacks'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:465:in `_update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:121:in `_update_record'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:900:in `create_or_update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:457:in `block in create_or_update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:824:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:457:in `create_or_update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:126:in `create_or_update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:474:in `save'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:47:in `save'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:298:in `block in save'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:298:in `save'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:628:in `block in update'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/klyda/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:626:in `update'
/home/klyda/findmypast/repos/press-freedom/images/reocr/database_breaker.rb:50:in `<main>'
D, [2021-08-31T13:50:26.078174 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   ReocrJob Load (352.6ms)  SELECT `reocr_job`.* FROM `reocr_job` WHERE `reocr_job`.`id` = 154 LIMIT 1
D, [2021-08-31T13:50:26.130003 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (49.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-08-31T13:50:26.180344 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   ReocrJob Update (49.9ms)  UPDATE `reocr_job` SET `reocr_job`.`status` = 'failed', `reocr_job`.`updated_at` = '2021-08-31 11:50:26' WHERE `reocr_job`.`id` = 154
D, [2021-08-31T13:50:26.445102 #1039883] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (264.0ms)  COMMIT
I, [2021-08-31T13:50:26.445227 #1039883]  INFO -- : Done. 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my Ruby version and some gems:

```
➜ ruby --version   
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
➜ gem list | grep 'activerecord\|mysql'
activerecord (6.1.4, 6.1.3.2, 5.2.6)
activerecord-import (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.5.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError` inherits from `StandardError`. That's why your `rescue StandardError` statement is catching it and executing the block below.

```rb
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError.ancestors
#=> [Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError, Mysql2::Error, StandardError, ...]
```

Comment: Yeah, of course, I'm not surprised that my rescue block is catching it rather than SQL query inside this block is working, and the one just before is throwing `Lost connection to MySQL server `. I'll maybe rephrase this sentence to be more clear ;)

Comment: Oh I get it, my bad. I guess your connection is still alive because your `connect_timeout` is greater than your `sleep` statement - but I can't give you a detailed answer. Maybe you could try setting a lowers timeouts to see how it behaves